# Best practicies to store session information in soap client app

Tags: c#, web-services, session, soap, web

I am developing an application which consumes soap service. Before using service methods my application calls authentication method which returns session information. I need to add this information to each soap request. Is there any best practicies to store this session information?

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: This is just a variable you pass on, you can keep it in any long lasting component of your app (e.g. a service of some sort).

Comment: Is this web application? If yes, store it in session. If this is desktop application - store it as a field of object calling soap service.

Answer (score 1):

You use any of the approaches mentioned above. The dot net framework does provide the EnableSession attribute. You may make use of it. Hope the below link helps :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession(v=vs.110).aspx